# Gulp: How to create a task that compiles multiple SASS files?

Tags: gulp

I have the following `sass` task which compiles `app.scss` to `app.css` and reloads the page:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Now, I want to compile another file, namely `ui-toolkit.scss` to `ui-toolkit.css`.

Is this the best way to update the task?

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('./ui-toolkit/ui-toolkit.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./ui-toolkit'));

  return gulp.src('./app/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just specify **[glob(s)](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options)** that match multiple scss files. These examples assume you want to save the results to same directory as the source file.

Matches **every** scss file (in node_modules too):

```js
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Matches scss files in specific dirs:

```js
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./{foo,bar}/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Matches only specific files (base option is needed here for saving to same directory as source file):

```js
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./foo/foo.scss', './bar/bar.scss'], { base: '.' })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Comment: sorry to dredge up an old post, but I'm getting an error when I try to do this, where it says  no such file './foo/foo.scss,./bar/bar.scss'... any ideas?  Also if I include base, I get "OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: --base="